# Ajax навигация с изменением http url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http, url

После нажатия на кнопку в меню происходит вызов функции которая отправляет Ajax запрос, после чего подгружается другой блок с контентом (динамическая подгрузка). После того как мы обновим страницу (уже с новым контентом), загруженный контент изменится на исходный контент на главной странице, т.е. как будто мы не нажали на блок в меню.

Как можно сделать что бы при обновлении страницы:

1. Оставался этот же блок с контентом ?
2. Изменялся http URL (чтобы указав его можно было сразу перейти на страницу с подгруженным контентом)?

Comment: изучайте `history.pushState()`. Кроме этого Вам нужно будет написать обработчик, который в зависимости от адреса будет отдавать нужный контент при загрузке страницы

Comment: Я знаю про это history но дело в том что когда все это прописываешь и первый раз нажимаешь все работает правильно но до того момента как ты обновляешь страницу

Comment: Вы написали обработчик, чтобы отдавался нужный контент при загрузке страницы в зависимости от адреса?

Comment: Да это не писал согласен но если честно я не особо представляю как его можно написать

Comment: Надо будет погуглить, но можете посоветовать статью какую-нибудь?

Comment: [Описание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API) и [пример на en](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Example). если простым языком, то  **в1** - для получения нужного контента отправлять ajax с параметрами адреса при загрузке страницы, **в2** на стороне сервера сразу собирать и отдавать нужную страницу в зависимости от параметров адреса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Описание объекта `history`, в т.ч. метода `history.history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API)

[Полный пример работы Ajax навигации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/Example)

Минимальный пример для общего понимания принципа работы [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API):

**test1.php:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="test1.php" class="test">загрузить текст для test1.php</a></li>  
  <li><a href="test2.php" class="test">загрузить текст для test2.php</a></li>  
</ul>
<div class="content"></div>
```

**test2.php:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="test1.php" class="test">загрузить текст для test1.php</a></li>  
  <li><a href="test2.php" class="test">загрузить текст для test2.php</a></li>  
</ul>
<div class="content"></div>
```

**test3.php**

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($_POST["page"]))
    {
        switch($_POST["page"]){
            case 'test1.php':
                echo 'это текст для страницы test1.php';
            break;
            case 'test2.php':
                echo 'это текст для страницы test2.php';
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

**test.js**

```
$(function(){

    function load_content()
    {
        $.post("test3.php", {page: location.pathname.substring(1)}, 
          function(data){
            $(".content").html(data);
        });
    }

    load_content();

    $(".test").on("click", function(){
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        history.pushState({param: 'Value'}, '', href);
        $.post("test3.php", {page: href}, function(data){
            $(".content").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

**Принцип работы:**
страницы `test1.php` и `test2.php` имеют одинаковый шаблон. После загрузки страницы 
 отправляем обработчику(`test3.php`) конечный адрес из url, который выдает нужный контент(текст) в зависимости от поступивших данных. Если на странице Вы нажмете на любую из ссылок, то произойдет добавление в историю новой записи(смена ссылки 
 через `history.pushState`) и выполнится запрос к обработчику, который вернет нужный контент.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Если контент это данные из БД, то можно сохранять в сессию или в куки  начало при выборке  допустим $start = 10;   И в функции котороя получает данные из БД проверять наличие переменной $start

Comment: Спасибо но все же это немножко не то)

Comment: А что за блоки?

Comment: Я про блоки в меню при нажатии на которые отправляется запрос Ajax