# Подгрузка страниц при прокрутке со сменой URL

Tags: ajax

Встречал на сайтах, например life ru, как при прокрутке к концу статьи - грузится автоматически следующая статья, при этом меняя в браузере URL.

В Интернете находил решения, но все они просто подгружают контент без смены URL.

Покажите пожалуйста примеры, можно просто ссылку.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/732317/191745

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ajax навигация с изменением http url](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732258/ajax-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-http-url)